# Transform only the styling of a Path2D

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, transformation, path-2d

In the canvas 2D API, we can first define a subpath using one context's transformation and then change that context's transformation for only the `fill()` or `stroke()` calls, which would have effect on the *stylings*, like `fillStyle`, `lineWidth` and other visible properties, but which will leave the sub-path as defined. This is quite convenient when we want to zoom in vector-shapes while keeping the same stroke-width.

Here is a simple example where only the `lineWidth` is affected by the variable *zoom* transformation:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

let zoom = 1;
let speed = 0.1;
requestAnimationFrame(update);

function update() {
  if( zoom >= 10 || zoom <= 0.1 ) speed *= -1;
  zoom += speed;
  draw();
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

function draw() {
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  // define the subpath at identity matrix
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(10 ,80);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(52.5,10,95,80);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(137.5,150,180,80);
  // stroke zoomed
  ctx.setTransform(zoom, 0, 0, zoom, 0, 0);
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

With the [Path2D](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Path2D) API, we have to pass this subpath directly in either `ctx.fill(path)` or `ctx.stroke(path)` methods.
This means we can't separate the stylings from the subpath declaration like we did before:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

let zoom = 1;
let speed = 0.1;
requestAnimationFrame(update);

function update() {
  if( zoom >= 10 || zoom <= 0.1 ) speed *= -1;
  zoom += speed;
  draw();
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

function draw() {
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  // define the subpath at identity matrix
  // (declared in 'draw' just for the example, would be the same anyway outside)
  const path = new Path2D("M 10 80 Q 52.5 10, 95 80 T 180 80");
  // stroke zoomed
  ctx.setTransform(zoom, 0, 0, zoom, 0, 0);
  ctx.stroke(path);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Is there no way of doing this while using this otherwise convenient Path2D API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a way to transform a Path2D object by passing a [DOMMatrix<sup>1</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMMatrix) to the [`Path2D.prototype.addPath`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Path2D/addPath) method.

So we can actually achieve the same result by passing a transformed copy of our Path2d:

```
const transformPath = (path, matrix) => {
  const copy = new Path2D();
  copy.addPath(path, matrix);
  return copy;
};
// ...
ctx.stroke( transformPath( path, {a: 1/zoom, d: 1/zoom } );
```

However, you'll notice that we have to make our *path-matrix* relatively from the *styling* one.
The new DOMMatrix API eases matrix transforms a lot<sup>2</sup>, but it makes this approach definitely more convoluted than the `beginPath()` way, that's quite unfortunate we can't act on the Path2D object itself or even just have this *transform* parameter on the constructor too, but that's the only way I know of...

```js
const transformPath = (path, matrix) => {
  const copy = new Path2D();
  copy.addPath(path, matrix);
  return copy;
};

const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
// define the subpath
const path = new Path2D("M 10 80 Q 52.5 10, 95 80 T 180 80");

let zoom = 1;
let speed = 0.1;
requestAnimationFrame(update);

function update() {
  if( zoom >= 10 || zoom <= 0.1 ) speed *= -1;
  zoom += speed;
  draw();
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

function draw() {
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);  
  // zoom the stylings
  ctx.setTransform(zoom, 0, 0, zoom, 0, 0);
  // create our transformed path
  const invertMatrix = {a: 1/zoom, d: 1/zoom};
  ctx.stroke(transformPath(path, invertMatrix));
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

<sup>1. Actually it doesn't need to be an actual DOMMatrix, any object with its properties will do</sup>
<sup>2. We can now even use such objects in `ctx.setTransform(matrix)`.</sup>

Comment: Total awesome now creating self similar paths for 2D context is a breeze as `addPath` can add to its self `p.addPath(p)` Useless on its own,  but with matrix all sorts of fractal like / repeating paths are possible.  Simple  and fast.. Example, a spiral containing 6000+ rects created with `p = new Path2D; p.rect(0,-5,10,10); i = 12; while (i--) { p.addPath(p, m.multiplySelf(m)) }`  with an init matrix `m = new DOMMatrix([0.99,0,0,0.99,6,0]).rotateSelf(0.03);`