# Is there a way to detect if a point is in a Path2D object after it has been rotated and translated?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, path-2d

I am trying to find a point in a Path2D object in an HTML5 canvas using JavaScript.

```
var path = new Path2D;
path.rect(0,0,100,100);
// declare the path

ctx.beginPath(); 
ctx.save()
ctx.translate(500,500);
ctx.rotate(Math.PI/2);
ctx.fill(path);
ctx.restore()
// draw the path after translation and rotation

ctx.isPointInPath(path,505,500) // return false because path is defined at 0, 0 not 500,500 where path is drawn
// Is there a way know if the points are in the path where it is drawn.
// I do not want to re - define the path, but if there is a way to move it that would work.
```

Please understand that this code is simplified, and the path I am using is not a generic shape, so this needs to work for any given 2d path. This is not a question about syntax so please excuse the undefined variables.

Comment: I had a similar problem where I upscaled the canvas by window.devicePixelRatio but had to do the same for x and y

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`isPointInPath()` takes its `x` and `y` coordinates as *untransformed*, i.e as absolute coordinates on the canvas, however it does apply the transformations on the given `path`.

So you need to call it with the applied transformation (i.e, get rid of this `ctx.restore()`).

However your numbers don't add up:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const path = new Path2D;
path.rect(0,0,100,100);
// declare the path

ctx.translate(500,500);
ctx.rotate(Math.PI / 2)
ctx.fillStyle = "green";
ctx.fill(path);

// using fixed values
const x = 505;
const y = 500;
console.log(ctx.isPointInPath(path,x,y));

// reset to identity matrix
ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillRect(x-2,y-2,4,4);

document.scrollingElement.scrollBy(600, 650);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="650"></canvas>
```

But if you use correct coordinates, it will work as expected:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const path = new Path2D;
path.rect(0,0,100,100);
// declare the path

ctx.translate(500,500);
ctx.rotate(Math.PI / 2)
ctx.fillStyle = "green";
ctx.fill(path);

// using fixed values
const x = 495;
const y = 505;
console.log(ctx.isPointInPath(path,x,y));

// reset to identity matrix
ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillRect(x-2,y-2,4,4);

document.scrollingElement.scrollBy(600, 650);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="650"></canvas>
```

And if one day you really need to transform a Path2D object, you can refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59677464/transform-only-the-styling-of-a-path2d/59677465#59677465) which uses the second parameter `matrix` of `Path2D.add(path, matrix)` to return a transformed copy of the Path2D object.